# I Can't set a validation message to an constraint

Tags: grails, exception, grails-orm

i have had some problems to set my constraint messages. Aparently, grails have problem to bind the message. Whem i display the errors validations messages i receive:

> - Field error in object 'br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson' on field 'alternativeDoc': rejected value [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus purus non erat tempus dictum. Nunc cursus tellus sed fermentum laoreet. Pellentesque vel ante dapibus, ullamcorper nisl id, rutrum ante. Etiam ex libero, aliquam consectetur orci aliquam.]; codes [br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.error.br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc,br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.error.alternativeDoc,br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.error.java.lang.String,br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.error,individualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.error.br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc,individualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.error.alternativeDoc,individualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.error.java.lang.String,individualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.error,br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.toobig.br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc,br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.toobig.alternativeDoc,br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.toobig.java.lang.String,br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.toobig,individualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.toobig.br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc,individualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.toobig.alternativeDoc,individualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.toobig.java.lang.String,individualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.toobig,size.toobig.br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson.alternativeDoc,size.toobig.alternativeDoc,size.toobig.java.lang.String,size.toobig]; arguments [alternativeDoc,class br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.IndividualPerson,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus purus non erat tempus dictum. Nunc cursus tellus sed fermentum laoreet. Pellentesque vel ante dapibus, ullamcorper nisl id, rutrum ante. Etiam ex libero, aliquam consectetur orci aliquam.,1,255]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] does not fall within the valid size range from [{3}] to [{4}]]

Soo, a input the data to invoke this exception intentionality. My problem is replace this worst error message to another.
My domain constraints code:

```
static constraints = {
    cpf unique: false, blank: true, nullable: true, size: 1..255
    rg blank: true, nullable: true, size: 1..255
    alternativeDoc blank: true, nullable: true, size: 1..255
    nationalityType blank: true, nullable: true, inList: ["B", "E"] 
    photo blank: true, nullable: true
    dateOfBirth blank: true, nullable: true
    gender blank: true, nullable: true, inList: Holders.config.individualPerson.gender
    nameOfFather size: 1..255
    nameOfMother blank: true, nullable: true, size: 1..255

    person blank: false, nullable: false
    maritalStatus blank: true, nullable: true
    race blank: true, nullable: true
    cityOfBirth blank: true, nullable: true
    countryOfBirth blank: true, nullable: true
}
```

And my messages.properties:

```
  individualPerson.cpf.size.error=Número de caracaretes inválio para cpf.
    individualPerson.cpf.blank=O cpf não pode estar em branco.
    individualPerson.cpf.nullable=O cpf não pode estar em branco.
    individualPerson.cpf.cpf=Cpf inválido.
    not.cpf=Cpf inválido.
    individualPerson.rg.size.error=Número de caracaretes inválio para rg.
    individualPerson.alternativeDoc.size.error=O número do documento deve conter entre 1 á 255 caracteres.
    individualPerson.nameOfFather.size.toobig=O nome para o Pai de conter de 1 á 255   caracteres.
    individualPerson.nameOfFather.size.toosmall=O nome para o Pai de conter de 1 á 255 caracteres.
    individualPerson.nameOfMother.size.error=O nome para a Mãe de conter de 1 á 255 caracteres.
    individualPerson.person.displayName.error=O nome para exibição de possuir entre 1 e 255 caracteres.

    person.name.size.error=O nome da pessoa de possuir entre 1 e 255 caracteres.
    person.displayName.size.error=O nome para exibição de possuir entre 1 e 255 caracteres.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set that field  "alternativeDoc" have MAX SIZE 255. You try to insert more chars.

Comment: You are right, i insert this purposely... to display the message. My question is how i customize this message?

Comment: Set more chars and change you changelog(migration plugin). This error in controller? You can user bindData(object, params, extends['alternativeDoc']) after it costumize this field. But the best-practise do it on UI